# In django do models have a default timestamp field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In django - is there a default timestamp field for all objects? That is, do I have to explicitly declare a 'timestamp' field for 'created on' in my Model - or is there a way to get this automagically?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

No such thing by default, but adding one is super-easy. Just use the `auto_now_add` parameter in the `DateTimeField` class:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

You can also use `auto_now` for an 'updated on' field. 
Check the behavior of `auto_now` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now).

For `auto_now_add` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add).

A model with both fields will look like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: For the "authetic" experience of timestamp field I add `editable=False` and recommend such, eg: `created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)`.

Comment: Note that using the `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` options causes the field to also have `editable=False`, so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 40):

Automagically doesn't sound like something django would do by default. It wouldn't force you to require a timestamp.

I'd build an abstract base class and inherit all models from it if you don't want to forget about the timestamp / fieldname, etc.

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
     created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     class Meta:
         abstract = True
```

It doesn't seem like much to import `wherever.TimeStampedModel` instead of `django.db.models.Model`

```
class MyFutureModels(TimeStampedModel):
    ....
```

Comment: There is also `model_utils` for Django which contains already `TimeStampedModel`, but if you don't need anything else from this package, just keep it w/o extra weight.

Comment: @boldnik I'm a fan of simplicity.

Comment: Pretty cool... I have 3 classes that needed a timestamp for `created` and `updated`. This is a great way of doing it cleanly.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/) (which is a good app for adding functionality to the django-admin.py command line helper) you can get these model fields for free by inheriting from [their TimeStampedModel](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/db/models.py) or using their [custom TimeStamp fields](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/db/fields/__init__.py#L153)

Answer (score 6):

You can try [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions)

if you want to use time-stamp abstract model

```
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel

class A(TimeStampedModel):
   ...
```

It has other abstract models. you can use that too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of `auto_now_add=True:`

For Date

```
from datetime import date

models.DateField(default=date.today)
```

For DateTime

```
from django.utils import timezone

models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you might be using IDs with your models, it's safe to use them this way.

```
from django.db import models
from uuid import uuid4


class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then import the TimeStampedModel in any model you want to use them, eg

```
class Detail(TimeStampedModel):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = "Detail"
       verbose_name_plural = "Details"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i would go with

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I need some clarifications on using

```
class TimeStampedModel(models.Model):
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
         abstract = True
```