# django does django have an automatic timestamp create/update field like cakephp?

Tags: django

having used cakephp in the past, one thing (perhaps the only thing?) i liked about it was that it had a "create" and "update" timestamp capability that was lovely - simply put, when you first added an item, the "create" date was set (assuming you named it right - create_date, i think)

Anytime thereafter, if an update was performed, the "update" field was set to the current time.

Does django have this as well? If so, what/how do i name the fields to get it to pick them up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In django do models have a default timestamp field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016412/in-django-do-models-have-a-default-timestamp-field)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Sure it has!

Check `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` in [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield)

Comment: From the [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#DateTimeField), it looks like they're mutually exclusive. But could you help to explain the difference? It isn't very clear what is the difference between `auto_now` and `auto_now_add`.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) clear up more. `auto_now` is generated on each edit, `auto_now_add` only generated on creation.

Answer (score 33):

It is not added to your model built-in in every table. You must add it as field to your model.

```
class Message(models.Model):

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Message in this case your table's name.