# Automatically changing Django model field on update for one field and freezing one-time write-only for another?

Tags: python, django

**Is there a `onupdate` parameter for Django's model fields?**

For example, in Flask with SQLAlchemy, it's possible to do something like the following with the `onupdate=...` parameter for the database schema's `db.Column()`:

```
import datetime

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    created_on = db.Column(db.Text, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
    updated_on = db.Column(db.Text, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat(), 
                           onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat())
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField), there's an `auto_now` parameter, is that the same thing as the `onupdate=...` parameter in in SQLAlchemy's `db.Column()`

I've tried the following model object to emulate the Flask's code above but how could I get the same `onupdate=...` "effect" in Django?

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now

class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    name = models.CharField(default='blah blah')
```

How do I "freeze" the value for the `create_on` field such that it can only be added once and never to be changed again afterwards?

But for the `updated_on`, it changes every time I change the values of the User, e.g. if I created a User and save, then change the `name` afterwards, `created_on` should remain the same but `updated_on` is automatically updated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django does django have an automatic timestamp create/update field like cakephp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979488/django-does-django-have-an-automatic-timestamp-create-update-field-like-cakephp)

Comment: Before addressing the substance of your question—all your examples are wrong in that you're passing the result of calling a function (`now()`) rather than the function itself (`now`). Let us know that that's not the source of your problem.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for noting that! Nope, that's not the source of the problem. Looks like the post to duplicated question might be related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In django you have the `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` optional arguments for `models.DateTimeField`

```py
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(default='blah blah')
```

`auto_now_add` will set the field to the current time when an object is created and `auto_now` will set the field to the current time when an object is created or updated.  You should be aware of some quirky behaviour though:

> The field is only automatically updated when calling Model.save(). The field isn’t updated when making updates to other fields in other ways such as QuerySet.update(), though you can specify a custom value for the field in an update like that.

More info in the docs at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField