# How do I model Django timestamps if I must import old data initially?

Tags: django, django-models, timestamp

I have some basic timestamp fields that should end up as `auto_now_add`:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

However, I need to seed the initial Django project database from an external database where these creation timestamps are already populated for existing data.

I imagine I may need to do the following:

1. Start with 
   `created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)`
2. Import old database data
3. Migrate to
   `created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`

Is this necessary to preserve the old timestamps, or can I start with the desired `auto_now_add` and import somehow while ignoring this?

Comment: How do you plan to import the data?

Comment: @grrrrrr Not sure how to answer that. There will be dump of a FilemakerPro database, then I imagine I need to write a Python script to map the fields of this database to the new Django project.

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8016412/7109869) may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for `auto_now_add`, using that flag will cause the field to be uneditable:

> As currently implemented, setting auto_now or auto_now_add to True will cause the field to have editable=False and blank=True set.

With that in mind you can just use `default=timezone.now` as you suggest and is mentioned in the docs.